# CSS rgba variables for I.E

Tags: css

I have some variables to easily define the color of my webapp, something like this:

```
:root {
    /*Variables for color style*/
  --main-bg-color: rgba(243, 243, 243, .7) !important;
}
```

The problem is that I.E. is not handling it. I solved it using preprocessor varialbes like this:

```
$main-bg-color: #fff
```

However, preprocessor variables can't handle rgba colors... Is there any way to store my rgba (without using one variable for each r, g, b, and alpha channel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rgba` not working in IE 6 & 7 (fixed in IE 8).

Try this:

```
:root { 
       background:transparent;
       filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000); 
       zoom: 1;
 }
```

[This may help you.](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)